# Having trouble with accessing array data from one class to another

Tags: java, arrays, scope, variable-assignment

I am having some trouble with passing data of an array from one class to the next.

*edits*
I am now no longer getting the error, and my code compiles, but as I had been warned, I got null for every element of the array. Now that I have taken out the static modifiers though, it still gives me null. I have also updated the code.

Here is the class where the array is created.

```
public class AssignSeat {

String[] arrangement = new String[12];

public void SeatStart() {

    arrangement[0] = "Collins";
    arrangement[2] = "Faivre";
    arrangement[3] = "Kinnard";
    arrangement[6] = "Morgans";
    arrangement[7] = "Rohan";
    arrangement[8] = "Shatrov";
    arrangement[9] = "Sword";
    arrangement[11] = "Tuckness";

    System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%n", "seat", "passenger");

    for (int i=0; i<arrangement.length; i++) {
        System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%n", i+1, arrangement[i]);

    }

}

public String[] getArrangement() {
    return arrangement;
}

public void setArrangement(String[] arrangement) {
    this.arrangement = arrangement;
}
}
```

and here is the method trying to access the information. It is specifically the for loop that I need help with so Ignore other areas where there are mistakes. Thank you.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    AssignSeat seat = new AssignSeat();

    if(event.getSource() instanceof JButton){

        JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
        String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();

        if (buttonText.equals("first class")) {
            entername.setVisible(true);
            seatnum.setVisible(true);
            confirmed.setVisible(true);
            inputline.setVisible(true);
            outputline.setVisible(true);
            if ((seat.arrangement[1] == null)) {
                System.out.println(seat.arrangement[0]);
                System.out.println(seat.arrangement[2]);
                two.setForeground(Color.green);
            }
        } else if (buttonText.equals("coach")) {
            //System.out.println("so does this!");
            entername.setVisible(true);
            seatnum.setVisible(true);
            confirmed.setVisible(true);
            inputline.setVisible(true);
            outputline.setVisible(true);
            if ((seat.arrangement[4] == null)) {
                five.setForeground(Color.green);
            } 
            if ((seat.arrangement[5] == null)) {
                six.setForeground(Color.green);
            } 
            if ((seat.arrangement[10] == null)) {
                eleven.setForeground(Color.green);
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the constructor that initializes the array is called before you try to access element `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the array was declared as `static`, but the initialization code for it is in the constructor. Remove all the `static` modifiers in the original code, and replace this part:

```
if (AssignSeat.getArrangement()[1].equals("null"))
```

With this:

```
AssignSeat assign = new AssignSeat();
if (assign.getArrangement()[1] == null)
```

Also notice that `"null"` is not a null value, use `null` (without quotes) for that.

A different approach would be to leave the array as an static member, but initialize it statically, like this:

```
private static String[] arrangement = new String[12];
static {
    arrangement[0] = "Collins";
    arrangement[2] = "Faivre";
    arrangement[3] = "Kinnard";
    arrangement[6] = "Morgans";
    arrangement[7] = "Rohan";
    arrangement[8] = "Shatrov";
    arrangement[9] = "Sword";
    arrangement[11] = "Tuckness";
}
```

In that case, this would work:

```
if (AssignSeat.getArrangement()[1] == null)
```

But I still believe that making the array `static` is going to be problematic if several instances of the class happen to be modifying its contents.

Comment: Why?  He's accessing it properly for a static variable.

Comment: @AdamLiss he's misunderstanding how to use a static member. He's initializing the array in the constructor, but accessing it statically  and the array clearly hasn't been initialized yet. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote ... I asked the question instead.  But the problem isn't the static declaration, it's the initialization.  I'd suggest you change your answer to show the proper initialization, which would probably be very helpful to the OP.

Comment: I just expanded my answer to make it more clear, for whoever downvoted without commenting the reason

Comment: @Óscar López Thank you for such an in depth answer. One thing I am unclear on is when I remove the static modifiers on everything, the setter method still suggests that it I should add it back and results in a compile error.

Comment: @LucasLusnikovHolloway also remove the `static` modifier from the getter and setter methods. Understand that a `static` member is the same for all instances of a class (therefore it's easy to modify it in unexpected ways) whereas a non-static, "instance" member will be different for each instance of a class, and what happens to one instance will not affect the others. Depending on the problem, one or the other might be needed

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (AssignSeat.getArrangement()[1].equals("null"))
```

with

```
if (AssignSeat.getArrangement()[1] == null)
```

If the value is `null`, you can't invoke methods (like `equals`) on it.  You need to compare the value directly to `null`, which is a constant rather than a string.

Comment: That solved the problem perfectly, except that there is an extra " mark in your answer. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do in the first class. You are initializing a static array from an instance method...

In other words, the String values in the array will be null until you call SeatStart from an instance of the class.

Try to initialize the String array from the static constructor for AssignSeat to make sure it has been initialized before you use it: http://www.snippetit.com/2009/05/java-static-variables-static-methods-and-static-constructor/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an attribute of a class, without instantiating the object first. Until you call a default/user-defined constructor, there is no memory dedicated to the attribute of that object.

Even though you manage to call the method you are using a static method, which can be called without an instance of the object being required.

Create a constructor for the object (or use a default constructor) and then you will be able to access your attribute because your object will be on the heap and have memory allocated for the string[].

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the SeaStart as an Array.

```
 public String[] SeatStart() {
        arrangement[0] = "Collins";
        arrangement[2] = "Faivre";
        arrangement[3] = "Kinnard";

        return arrangement;
    }
```

For convinience, make a new array to copy the array from **AssignSeat** class. Then retrieve the value from that array.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
    AssignSeat seat = new AssignSeat();

    String[] foo = seat.SeatStart();

    System.out.println(foo[0]);
    System.out.println(foo[1]);
    System.out.println(foo[2]);
}
```

Though you can acces it also with:

`System.out.println(seat.SeatStart()[0]);`

The result would be:

```
Collins
null
Faivre
```

and that 'null' is because apparently you haven't allocate a value for arrangement[1] :-)

But in the end, it works.